# Как подключить font-awesome?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, fontawesome

Установил font-awesome (4.7), пишу в компоненте:

```
<style scoped>
  @import '@fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
</style>
```

Или пробовал еще так: `@import url('../node-modules/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')`. Все равно выдает ошибки. Как правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Для бесплатной версии шрифтов**

в зависимостях:

```
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.2",
```

установка:

```
yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

в main.js

```
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css'
```

ну и использование в темплейтах:

```
<i class="fas fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: А можете с Бутстрапом подсказать? Точно также установил. Пишу по аналогии `import '@bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'`, но мне ругается `module not found`. Хотя путь точно такой - я проверил.

Comment: Очень странно, но с Бутстрапом проблема решилась удалением собаки. А fontawesome без нее не работает. В чем разница? О_о

Comment: @ - это функция NPM под названием 'scoped packages', которая эффективно позволяет размещать пакеты NPM в пространстве имен. Каждый пользователь и организация на NPM имеют свою собственную область действия, и только они могут добавлять в нее пакеты.